# NSPredicate on multiple to-many relationships in Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

I have an `NSPredicate` which includes multiple aggregate filters, which is throwing an exception.

I have the following core data model:

[image: Core data model]

I want to pick those `ApparelItems` for which any of the `colours` has an `rgb` of 13576743, and for which all of the `picks` have a `pickTime` earlier than a given `NSDate`.

My code to create the predicate is:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "ApparelItem")
var predicates = [NSPredicate]()

predicates.append(NSPredicate(format: "ANY colours.rgb = 13576743"))

// find the NSDate representing midnight x days ago
let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
if let xDaysAgo = cal.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: -2, toDate: NSDate(), options: [])
{
    let midnightXDaysAgo = cal.startOfDayForDate(xDaysAgo)

    predicates.append(NSPredicate(format: "(ALL picks.pickTime < %@)", midnightXDaysAgo))
}

request.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: predicates)

let searchData = try? objectContext.executeFetchRequest(request)
```

I get the following exception:

```
Exception name=NSInvalidArgumentException, reason=Unsupported predicate (ANY colours.rgb == 13576743) AND ALL picks.pickTime < CAST(479347200.000000, "NSDate")
```

I have tried:

1. Each individual predicate works fine. Ie `ANY colours.rgb = ...` works, also `ALL picks.pickTime < ...` works. They just don't work when combined into the same query.
2. Combining the two using into a single query, linked with `AND`, rather than using `NSCompoundPredicate`. Result is the same.

Is it possible that core data simply doesn't support filtering on more than one to-many relationship? That would seem odd. In which case how should I do the above?

Comment: One possible way out, depending on the cardinality of the tables in questions, would be to do the most selective filtering in core data the the second one in memory using `filteredArrayUsingPredicate`

Comment: Thanks... agree that's possible, but it seems really inefficient. For one thing (though it's not shown in the code above, which is a simplified version) I'm actually only asking core data for its `ManagedObjectId`s. I therefore don't actually have the objects to perform work on. Again, that's obviously something that I could change, but I've done it that way to keep memory usage low.

Comment: have you tried using subquery ?

Comment: try using each predicate individually and see if one of them is responsible or if it's compounding them together that causes the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably could try `SUBQUERY()` for `NSPredicate`.

The code below I came out from some guess and not very sure if it works or not. Usually it takes me trial and error many times for a to-many query clause with `NSPredicate`.

```
var predicates = [NSPredicate]()
predicates.append(NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(colours, $colour, ANY $colour.rgb = 13576743).@count > 0"))
let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
if let xDaysAgo = cal.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: -2, toDate: NSDate(), options: []) {
    let midnightXDaysAgo = cal.startOfDayForDate(xDaysAgo)
    predicates.append(NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(picks, $pick, ALL $pick.pickTime < %@).@count > 0", midnightXDaysAgo))
}
```

Comment: That seems to work. For reference I only needed to change one predicate to a subquery. So I changed the date one for  `predicates.append(NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(picks, $pick, $pick.pickTime > %@).@count = 0", midnightXDaysAgo))` (slightly different to what you had, but same concept.) Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Colors and picks are two different entities, so you should be able to filter by both without using `SUBQUERY`. One predicate or a compound predicate should both be fine.

From the error message it seems that perhaps something is wrong with the date. Please check you have the expected data type in your managed object subclasses. If you used "primitive values" when creating the subclasses, you will need `NSTimeInterval` rather than `NSDate`.